# Rails migration add_column with existing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

Using Rails and MYSQL. Existing table has a column called c1, I would like to add a column called c2 with data func(c1), func is the model method to deal with c1 data. How should I write the migration? Thanks

Comment: if my answer helped you please click on check mark left side next to my answer so i can get reputations points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. rails generate migration add_something_to_tablename something:string
2. rake db:migrate
3. Inside that model

add this line

```
before_save :do_something
```

add this method

```
private
  def do_something
    do something with c1
  end
```